# Item purchasing using urllib

Tags: python, http, url

I have this function that gets an item passed from another function, together with the subtotal and the fee of the item. The function has to act as fast as possible, as other people also want the item. However, the function seems to take a very long time, and almost never ends up buying the actual item because it was too late.

```
def buy(self, listingid, subtotal, fee):
    print('ATTEMPT')
    buy_url = BUY_URL + listingid
    values = {'sessionid' : self.sessionid,
              'currency' : '3',
              'subtotal' : str(subtotal),
              'quantity' : '1',
              'total' : str(subtotal + fee),
              'fee' : str(fee)
              }
    headers = {'Referer' : BASE + urllib.parse.quote(self.item)}
    print(buy_url, values, headers)
    post = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    binary_data = post.encode('utf-8')
    request = urllib.request.Request(buy_url, binary_data, headers)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
    data = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))
```

Is there any way I can (codewise) speed this function up? There are no exceptions, so that's not to worry about.

Note: I have removed the `print()`s in the real function

Comment: The overall time taken by this function to execute will be, no doubt, dominated by the time it spends doing the network calls, which is not in your power to change. I don't see anything that would stand out in your code. I would probably import stuff from `urllib` differently, so that I wouldn't need to write that much. Also, if the output produced by `print` is there to stay, I'd rather use `logging`.

Comment: Consider using [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) which has an easier to use and more modern API. It's also Python 3 compatible.

Comment: @sebix yeh I considered that but is it faster? I dont think so because it uses urllib as well right?

Comment: If you want to be as fast as possible, write a c program and work with raw data. http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/#testimonials

Comment: What exactly takes a long time in your code? Can you profile it and understand what is the slowest point? Code looks completely fine - I don't think c++ version will be faster (only theoretically) - because this is just querying the site with simple HTTP request.

Profile the whole program - maybe this is not actually the bottleneck?